# How can I switch to the most recent frame with other-frame?

Tags: frames

The function `other-frame` cycles through the open frames in a fixed order. This can be pretty inconvenient for example when the compiling log of LaTeX comes to the front, I want to switch back to my `.tex` document and I have plenty of other frame opened at the same time. On the major GUIs I know the window or application switching command switch between the most recent ones (and on can access the other ones by repeating the command).

Comment: I realize you want the most recent, but there are functions available by Googling that work with `ido`, or selecting a frame by name, or selecting a frame by letter (of available options), or selecting a frame by number (of available options).  That way you can go immediately to whichever frame you really want.  Off hand, I don't know of a most-recent select frame function -- but if it doesn't exist, I'm sure someone will write it up.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code I ended up writing to accomplish this.  Add the following to your `init.el` file, and bind a key to `my-goto-most-recent-frame`:

```
(defvar my-recent-frames '())

(defun my-frame-record-selected ()
  "Record the currently selected frame.  Add this to the focus-in-hook."
  (let ((f (selected-frame)))
    (setq my-recent-frames (cons f (remove f my-recent-frames)))))

(add-hook 'focus-in-hook #'my-frame-record-selected)

(defun my-goto-most-recent-frame ()
  "Jump to most recently active frame before the current frame."
  (interactive)
  (unless (null my-recent-frames)
    (select-frame-set-input-focus (car (cdr my-recent-frames)))))
```